# Android motion sensor

Tags: android, sensors, motion

I want to capture the event when user put device in the ear(Ex. To hear phone call) and also when user remove device from the ear.
Basically  i want to capture

- start time in ear.
- end time in ear.

Please help.

Comment: Your question lacks research. This is not a good fit for SO's question standards. Please visit [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out what kind of questions you should ask here.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the Android site, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

It sounds like you'll need to use a combo of ACCELEROMETERs and Gyroscopses to detect when the phone is lifted up and rotated to be near the ear.

Comment: Hi Dan, I am working on same API you have suggested. I am able to capture the event when we bring device near to the ear. but i want to capture event when device is far from ear. Ex in user pocket.

Comment: Do you have an earpiece connected to the phone then?

Comment: No, without ear phone only. I am using PROXIMITY sensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY).